# Can I use AWS KMS encryption for client side encryption in Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

There is no method for KMS encryption in Android AWS SDK. On the server side we use `KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider` to create `AmazonS3EncryptionClient` object, but this class is not available in Android SDK. I tried using the Java SDK in my Android project but it threw an exception

Code:

```
KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider materialProvider = new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(kms_cmk_id);
encryptionClient = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider(), materialProvider,
                new CryptoConfiguration())
            .withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
```

Exception

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "javax.management.MBeanServerFactory" on path: DexPathList

Comment: Android is a subset of Java. Java SDK probably wont work

Comment: what is your use case?

Comment: @ketanvijayvargiya please see the updated question

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Business use case, I mean.

Comment: @ketanvijayvargiya i am trying to secure the data transfer to amazon s3 bucket, follow this link [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/client-side-using-kms-java.html)

Comment: I hope you know that Kms supports very less TPS. So if your android app is going to be used by lot of people, you shouldn't be using KMS. Check their limits first.

Comment: @ketanvijayvargiya but is it possible to implement it on the android side?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I'll give you three options, but all of them require getting your hands a little dirtier.

Option 1: You can derive your own implementation of a KMS Encryption Materials Provider. Even though that specific class (and likely some of its dependencies) are not present in the AWS Android SDK, you have the interface you need on the SDK: [EncryptionMaterialsProvider](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/EncryptionMaterialsProvider.java). It should be possible to implement your own provider based on that.

Option 2: Use the KMS Client provided in the Android SDK to retrieve your own encryption materials from KMS and then pass a [StaticEncryptionMaterialsProvider](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/StaticEncryptionMaterialsProvider.java) to the S3 client.

Option 3: Deal with encryption/decryption yourself. It's technically possible for you to retrieve the encryption materials using the KMS client, and then follow the KMS guidance on the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html) to encrypt/decrypt your data. Please just do this if you are comfortable with cryptography.